# Modern Multilingual Sites, Pages, News in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

Microsoft deprecated **Variations** features in SharePoint 2019 ([Reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019)) and not available in Modern SharePoint Sites as well.

What will be the actions, if we have an requirement to build Modern SharePoint 2019 Web Application in bilingual (English / Arabic)

- Modern SharePoint Online Supports Multilingual Sites. ([Reference 2](https://blog.mydock365.com/translate-sharepoint-site-to-multiple-languages))
- Modern SharePoint On-Premises 2019 we don't have that below option:

  **Enable Pages and news to be translated into multiple languages**

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this? Please share if you did

Comment: No ootb option available in Modern SP 2019. Custom WebParts are the solution, store lang value in local storage and based on that changes the dir=rtl or others..